# Inline-block not working with images inside li

Tags: html, css, html-lists, overflow

I've images in each `li` tag. I am trying to show only one image at the start. So I am trying to hide the remaining by giving `overflow: hidden` to the parent.
But the `inline-block` is not working for `li` element.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="carousel">
    <ul>
      <li><img src="https://dummyimage.com/280X450/ccc/fff.png&text=Test1" /></li>
      <li><img src="https://dummyimage.com/280X450/fcb/fff.png&text=Test2" /></li>
      <li><img src="https://dummyimage.com/280X450/333/fff.png&text=Test3" /></li>
      <li><img src="https://dummyimage.com/280X450/cfb/fff.png&text=Test4" /></li>
      <li><img src="https://dummyimage.com/280X450/ccd/fff.png&text=Test5" /></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
  background: #3bc;
}
.container {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.carousel {
  width: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  vertical-align: top;
  white-space: normal;
}
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/iamraviteja/pen/OgegEQ?editors=0100)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot have `inline-block` as well as `float: left`. The `display` is right. All you need to do is, add `white-space: nowrap` and get rid of the `float`:

```css
body {
  background: #3bc;
}
.container {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.carousel {
  width: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;     /* Add this and remove float. */
}
ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  white-space: normal;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="carousel">
    <ul>
      <li><img src="https://dummyimage.com/280X450/ccc/fff.png&text=Test1" /></li>
      <li><img src="https://dummyimage.com/280X450/fcb/fff.png&text=Test2" /></li>
      <li><img src="https://dummyimage.com/280X450/333/fff.png&text=Test3" /></li>
      <li><img src="https://dummyimage.com/280X450/cfb/fff.png&text=Test4" /></li>
      <li><img src="https://dummyimage.com/280X450/ccd/fff.png&text=Test5" /></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am not using Flexbox for the reason of lack of support and new technology.

Comment: Your comment about flexbox seems a bit out of place, check: http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox

Comment: @RenevanderLende IE 8 or 9 doesn't support flexbox yet... `:)` Still waiting for a day when all banks get rid of IE 6... `:D`

Comment: That is true and I have no idea how much IE8 is used in your region of the world, but support for IE8 has gone too

Comment: @RenevanderLende True. Check my updated comment... `:)` Umm... I am in the heart of England...

Comment: Got your point, but you might consider using `dumb-ass-bank.css` and a `the-rest-of-us.css` with no and full flexbox. Just a thought... Huh?!?! England, that changes my perspective on the world entirely (I'm from NL).

Comment: @RenevanderLende Do you seriously want me to get chucked out of my corp? `;P`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149587/discussion-between-rene-van-der-lende-and-praveen-kumar).

Answer (score 0):

The `float:left` takes the `li` elements out of the document flow. In the code below I removed the `float` and am using a flexbox instead.

```css
body {
  background: #3bc;
}

.container {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.carousel {
  width: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="carousel">
    <ul>
      <li><img src="https://dummyimage.com/280X450/ccc/fff.png&text=Test1" /></li>
      <li><img src="https://dummyimage.com/280X450/fcb/fff.png&text=Test2" /></li>
      <li><img src="https://dummyimage.com/280X450/333/fff.png&text=Test3" /></li>
      <li><img src="https://dummyimage.com/280X450/cfb/fff.png&text=Test4" /></li>
      <li><img src="https://dummyimage.com/280X450/ccd/fff.png&text=Test5" /></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```